# Comparing attributes from a List inside a List

Tags: c#, .net, list, oop, string-comparison

**Description**
My goal is to compare the language of a menu object from the `menuList`. Since the `menuList` has the Languages offered as another list it makes it a bit more complicated. So I tried to create a new class object with the same values so I can use menuList.Languages.Contains(languageObject), however I quickly found out that this doesn't work like that. I tried to make a for loop inside a for loop which didn't work either, but could be a failure from my side.

Obviously I can't write something like:

```
MenuList.Languages.Name.Equals("English").
```

Because of that I am looking for a solution where I can check if the attribute Name of the Languages-List inside the menuList equals a value of my choice.

**The Object**

```
private LanguageBox LangEng = new LanguageBox
{
    IsoCode = "eng",
    Name = "English"
};
```

**The List**

```
var MenuList = menuDataClient.GetMenuByCity(city)
    .Select(nap => new MenuBox()
    {
        Menu = nap.Menu,
        Languages = nap.Languages
            .Select(lang => new LanguageBox()
            {
                IsoCode = lang.IsoCode,
                Name = lang.Name
            }).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

**The Loop**

```
for (int i = 0; i < MenuList.Count; i++)
{
   if (MenuList[i].Languages.Contains(LangEng))
   {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Success");
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like `(MenuList[i].Languages.Contains(x => x.Name.Equals(LangEng)))`

Comment: Hi, it sound to me like this is a case for a `join`; can you show the list data, the things you want to select and the desired output?

Comment: You can define the `IEqualityComparer` and use the overload of `Contains`. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-5.0#System_Linq_Enumerable_Contains__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0____0_System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__). Use this ff you want to compare the whole object. If want to compare only name then use the suggestions mentioned by @Quercus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. This LINQ option works if you want to only keep elements in the list which have English or Russian in their Languages-List.

**Solution**

```
.Where(lang => lang.Languages.Any(any => any.Name.Equals("English") || any.Name.Equals("Russian")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe linq's Where could do the trick? Sth like:

```
foreach(var item in MenuList)
{
   var x = item.Languages.Where(obj => obj.Name == <desired language>);
   if (x.Count() > 0)  
   {
       //Success code
       break;
   }
}
```